# ¿Porque no devuelve nada el comando?

Tags: html, script, backend, cgi

Tengo ese formulario sencillo que captura un dato y lo manda a un script cgi para que busque un usuario a partir de ese dato,no entiendo porque: `resultado=$(grep -w $dato /etc/passwd)` funciona perfecto pero `nombre =$(grep -w $dato /etc/passwd | cut -d ":" -f1)` no devuelve nada, siendo que en la terminal reemplazo dato por un nombre de usuario o UID y funciona.

```
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
      </head>

      <body>
        <h1>Forumario web</h1>
        <form method="get" action="/cgi-bin/backend.cgi">
        Ingrese dato: <input type="text" name="dato">
        <input type="submit" value="enviar dato">
        </form>
      </body>
    </html>
```

```
    #!/bin/bash
    echo "Content-type: text/html"
    echo ""
    tempIFS = $IFS
    IFS='&'
    eval $QUERY_STRING

    resultado=$(grep -w $dato /etc/passwd)
    nombre =$(grep -w $dato /etc/passwd | cut -d ":" -f1)
      echo "datos: $resultado </br>"
      echo "el nombre es : $nombre </br>"


    IFS = $tempIFS
    exit 0
```

Comment: ya lo solucioné,el error es el espacio que hay entre la variable nombre y el = ,esto es nuevo para mi,disculpen,borro la pregunta o la dejo?

Comment: Yo soy un recién llegado, pero pienso que debieras validar la pregunta como respondida y dejarla: a alguien le valdrá.

Comment: ni idea como hacer jaja,pone lo que yo puse y lo califico como la respuesta correcta ;)

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour